# Struggling on creating a simple shape

Tags: android, shapes

I am used this from the android developers but don't understand why it force closes:

package com.example.shapedrawable.CustomDrawableView;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.OvalShape;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomDrawableViewActivity extends View {
    private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;

    public CustomDrawableViewActivity(Context context) {
    super(context);

    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    int width = 300;
    int height = 50;

    mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
    mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);
    mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
    }
```

Comment: You need to click on DDMS button and look into LogCat. There filter messages by clicking on little E button and then run you app. It should show you what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say *where* it force closes which is always useful information, but I assume it's at this line:

```
mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

`getPaint()` will return null until you call `setPaint()`. Try this:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
mDrawable.setPaint(paint);
```

Comment: Thanks but it still force closes and honestly i am not sure where it is going wrong